# Javascript preventDefault operation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I'm just practising some JavaScript and I came across an error I can't get around. I have a list in my html where each item links to a page, but
I have a function in my js script where when I click the item its supposed to remove the item from the list, I'm trying to use `preventDefault()` but it still takes me to that link.

```
<ul id="shoppingList">
        <li class="complete"><a href="google.com><em>fresh</em>tuna</a></li>
        <li class="complete"><a href="google.com">meatball</a></li>
        <li class="complete"><a href="google.com">kiwi</a></li>
        <li class="complete"><a href="google.com">chicken soup</a></li>
    </ul> 

function getTarget(e){
if(!e){
    e = window.event;
} 
return e.target || e.srcElement;}

function itemDone(e){
//Remove item from the list
var target;
var Parent;
var Grandparent;
target = getTarget(e);
Parent = target.parentNode;
Grandparent = target.parentNode.parentNode;
Grandparent.removeChild(Parent);

//Prevent the link from taking you somewhere
if(e.preventDefault){
    e.preventDefault();
}else{
    e.returnValue = false;
}
}

//Set up event listeners to call ItemDone() on click
var Shoppo = document.getElementById('shoppingList');
if(Shoppo.addEventListener){
Shoppo.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    itemDone(e);
},flase);
}else{
Shoppo.attachEvent('onClick',function(e){
    itemDone(e);
});
}
```

Comment: `if(e.preventDefault)` what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: if preventDefault works

Comment: never thought of it, is there a way to know if event.preventDefault is in use?

Comment: Older versions of IE explorer doesn't take prevent default, so i went with the returnValue statment

Comment: Check your spelling - `flase`..

Comment: Thanks Roamer1888 that was it, one little type can cause your whole page not work.

Comment: And since you tagged the question [jQuery] ..... `$('#shoppingList').on('click', function itemDone(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent().remove();
});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if the `e.preventDefault()` was called, you can use `isDefaultPrevented` which returns true or false. So you can change your code like this,

```
e.preventDefault();
if(e.isDefaultPrevented()){
    // default event is prevented
}else{
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: This is still taking me to my links.

Comment: This does work my apologies, my a comment above is misspelled false with flase, in another part of my code.

Answer (score 2):

Change this :

```
if(e.preventDefault){
    e.preventDefault();
}else{
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```

to this:

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

This will work, and save you a couple of lines of code.

Comment: This still sends me to the a link.

Comment: My apologies, this does work, i just had a typo of false elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the browser to follow the link but still need the url, you could store it in in a different attribute and set the href to #.

```
<a href="#" id="link1" destinationurl="www.google.com" ... />
```

Then you could use the getAttribute function to retrieve the value

```
document.getElementById("link1").getAttribute("destinationurl");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the situation, that

```
ev.preventDefault();
ev.stopPropagation();
```

and even

```
document.onclick= function(ev){ev.preventDefault(); ev.stopPropagation(); return false;}
```

did not help at all

as I used touchstart, touchend, touchmove to create mousedown, onmouseup and mousemove events.

On desktop, there was no issue, but using the same code on mobiles, everything doubled (sometimes on the same call ???) in the console.

I could solve the problem with this code :

```
var clickUpMouseEventTimer = 0; 

function clickUp(ev) {
   ev = ev || event;

   console.log('clickUp mouse timer' ,ev['timeStamp'], ev['timeStamp'] -clickUpMouseEventTimer)

   if( clickUpMouseEventTimer + 200 < ev['timeStamp']) {
       clickUpMouseEventTimer = ev['timeStamp'];
   } else {
       return;
   }
```

This way I could intercept whatever mousedown or mouseup event, if fired doubled by measuring :

ev['timeStamp'],

and decide by offering a latency of 200ms (this depends on your program execution time), wether to drop the input or let it pass the function.

The magic worked finest and desktop and mobile are doing now exactly the same steps (except the touch to mouse event translator).

Hope it can help, as you guys did help me a lot and many times with your experiences and knowledge.